# match any of these strings in url

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'd like to use regex to determine if a url includes any of a number of strings (say "string1" OR "string2" )

I tried string1|string2.  Not working.  Ideas?

===========

Codespy's solution below works for the above. thx!  However looking to modify my question a bit more. What if I want to do the following:

1. match "abcd" OR "efgh" OR ( any url that includes BOTH "IJKL" AND ".MP3)

Comment: don't know javascript or jquery

Comment: Where are you using this regex?

Comment: In a google analytics filter

Comment: I've posted the answer. I tested it here in this url : http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester , works fine.

Comment: can you make it little more clear giving a demo?? It's possible, simply change the expression.

Comment: @user2022284 I think you should really [learn regex](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Comment: Updated the answer. You can try. RegExp is really something cool. You'll enjoy that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following RegExp to solve your scenario.

```
//to match a stringX (X is any digit) pattern string
string[0-9]*

//to match any words 
[A-Za-z]*

//matches anything.mp3
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.mp3)$
```

[**A Demo of RegExp using jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/P3m3a/)